# MVC & SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

Is there a way to output select list to a string in the View ?

```
//Javascript
var comboHtml = <%= Html.Encode(Model.MySelectList.ToHtml()) %>
```

or would i have to enumerate the list my self to create the html,

need this for a dynamic form field.

Comment: If you need the value in javascript you should javascript encode it.
Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var comboHtml = '<%= Html.DropDownList("name", Model.MySelectList) %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax and Html.RenderPartial.

(assuming mvc.net btw)

Also, the issue with doing it in Javascript is that the <%= stuff here %> would render the string at the page load.